# Using QUERY URL to group data before sending to Google Apps Script dashboard

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet, with say a key 'ABCKEY' and would like to perform the QUERY (SQL) function on the data before using the data in a Google Apps Script dashboard.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ABCKEY');
var mydata = ss.getDataRange();
```

[This article](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1388882) explains how one can use the QUERY feature on the data in the spreadsheet to produce grouped data.

The following query produces the correct grouped data I would like to use as the data source of my Google Apps Script dashboard:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/a/mybusinessappdomain.com/tq?key=ABCKEY&tq=select%20A%2CC%2Csum(F)%2Csum(G)%20group%20by%20A%2C%20C
```

I would therefore essentially like to populate the `mydata` variable above with the result from the above SQL query, which produces a JSON output string.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I propose is this:

1. Use `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` to get the results of the query uri into a variable in your script.  The query URI returns javascript to set results for the google visualization service.
2. Remove any extraneous content in the result, leaving only the JSON representation of the query results. A simple regex extraction can do this, and then we can parse the extracted string into a JSON object.
3. Decode the JSON object into a two-dimensional array, `mydata`. This requires some understanding of how the table is represented as a JSON object in the visualization query.

The JSON query result is structured like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.6",
  "status": "ok",
  "sig": "862651648",
  "table": {
    "cols": [
      {
        "id": "A",
        "label": "",
        "type": "string",
        "pattern": ""
      },
      {
        "id": "D",
        "label": "Population Density",
        "type": "number",
        "pattern": "#0.###############"
      }
    ],
    "rows": [
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "Indonesia"
          },
          {
            "v": 117,
            "f": "117"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "China"
          },
          {
            "v": 137,
            "f": "137"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "Nigeria"
          },
          {
            "v": 142,
            "f": "142"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "Pakistan"
          },
          {
            "v": 198,
            "f": "198"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "India"
          },
          {
            "v": 336,
            "f": "336"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "Japan"
          },
          {
            "v": 339,
            "f": "339"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "c": [
          {
            "v": "Bangladesh"
          },
          {
            "v": 1045,
            "f": "1045"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You'll notice that the `table` object consists of an array of `cols` objects that describe the columns in the table. For your array, the portion that you're interested in is the `label` for the column.

After that, the `table` object contains an array of `rows` objects, each with an array of `c` objects with the data for each column in the row. For your array, it's the `v` or value that you're interested in. (`f` contains a formatted version of the same data)

So our parser will iterate through the column headers first, then through each row of the table, `push`ing the values-of-interest into a two-dimensional array, `mydata`.

For this example, I'm accessing the public spreadsheet used in the [Interactive Code Sample](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#using_the_query_language) provided in the [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Setting_the_Query_from_JavaScript), and also using their sample query. I've written the example so it can be easily modified to access your own spreadsheet with your own query. Here's the code:

```
  // Specify the spreadsheet key and the query to be retrieved
  var ssKey = 'pCQbetd-CptGXxxQIG7VFIQ';
  var query = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A,D WHERE D > 100 ORDER BY D');

  // Build url to peform query
  var url = 'http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=%KEY%&tq=%QUERY%'
          .replace('%KEY%',ssKey)
          .replace('%QUERY%',query);

  // Use UrlFetchApp to get the results of the query as a string.
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var content = response.getContentText();
  //Logger.log(content);

  // Extract the JSON object from the response. Note that the response contains
  // multiple lines of Javascript, and that it's the second line that has our
  // data table in it.
  var regex = /.*google.visualization.Query.setResponse\((.*)\)/g
  var jsonContent = regex.exec(content)[1];
  Logger.log(jsonContent);
  var objectContent = Utilities.jsonParse(jsonContent);

  var numCols = objectContent.table.cols.length;
  var numRows = objectContent.table.rows.length;

  // Decode objectContent into a two-dimensional array.
  var mydata = []
  // Start with the header row.
  mydata[0] = [];
  for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++ ) {
    mydata[0].push(objectContent.table.cols[col].label);
  }
  // Then data rows
  for (var row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
    mydata[row+1] = [];
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++ ) {
      mydata[row+1].push(objectContent.table.rows[row].c[col].v);
    }
  }

  // Done - mydata is now a two-dimensional array with the results of the query
  debugger;  // If debugging, pause to examine results
```

Depending on what you're planning to use the data for in your dashboard, you may just want to use the `table` object after the call to `jsonParse()`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the json parser `var objectContent = Utilities.jsonParse(jsonContent)` would work with those visualization  query response having date as one of the cell value such as the below example

```
{
    "v": newDate(2013,
    11,
    31),
    "f": "31-Dec-2013",
    "p": {
        "style": "color: rgb(0, 0, 0);font-family:Dialog;"
    }
}
```