# How to Perform a Lookup/Filter Across Google Spreadsheets Using Google Apps Script

Tags: filter, google-apps-script, gs-vlookup

I would like to use Google Apps Script to populate a spreadsheet with filtered data from another spreadsheet.

The source document is a list of employees (column A, NAME), with their reported hours (column B, HOURS), the project they are working on (column C, PROJECT), and their specific task (column D, TASK).

I would like to populate the second spreadsheet with the same information, but only where the PROJECT equals "Project X" and the Task equals either "Task 1" or "Task 2."

I know how to do this without scripts in the source document, but Google spreadsheets does not allow VLookup, or any other lookup function that I am aware of, to lookup values across separate documents.  Importing the source data to the second spreadsheet using ImportRange does not work in this case because the source data is too large (ultimately, this script will have to be altered to look at several source documents since there is too much data for one spreadsheet).

I am sorry I have no code.  My attempts to solve this problem on my own have gotten me nowhere.

Thank you!

Comment: You should break down your problem into smaller problems. First try to write a script that will copy all data from one spreadsheet to another. Then include a filter to copy only those matching a particular value in Col A and so on... While you're doing this, if you get stuck, feel free to come back to SO with whatever you've attempted and the community will help. However, if you are seeking readymade code, unfortunately this is not the place

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful.  I am trying to learn javascript just to answer this one problem, but it's going slowly.  Basically, I've searched the resources on Google spreadsheets and everyone just says this is a problem that needs to be solved with Apps Script.  Trying to break out how to actually do this in Apps Script kept bringing me here.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you cant, psrticularly if the data is large.
you might be able to do it writting the formula with script (using vlookup or query) but that has limitations, for example you have to take turns if more than one script runs simultaneously.
Another more robust way is to use urlfetch with the spreadsheets api. Use the list rows api with a "q" filter. That works well even with simultaneous scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly old thread, but there are so few examples of how to do this that I thought one more couldn't hurt. You can pass an SQL statement into the querySpreadsheet() function below, something like:

```
var querySQL = "SELECT A, B, C, D WHERE C = 'Project X' AND (D = 'Task 1' OR D = 'Task 2')";
```

You can then drop the array of data returned by the function into your target sheet like so:

```
var aryValues = querySpreadsheet(querySQL);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('OUTPUT_TOPLEFT_CELL').offset(0, 0, aryValues.length, 4).setValues(aryValues);
```

These functions are almost good to go, just substitute your information where indicated.
Credit to Mogsdad for the original of this script here: 
[Using QUERY URL to group data before sending to Google Apps Script dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962933/using-query-url-to-group-data-before-sending-to-google-app-script-dashboard)

```
function querySpreadsheet(querySQL){ 

try {  

  //you can find both these items in the url of your spreadsheet
  var ssKey = 'DOCUMENT KEY OF THE DATA SOURCE SPREADSHEET INSIDE THESE QUOTES - long code ends with "&" starts with "key="';
  var gId = 'INDEX OF THE SHEET CONTAINING THE DATA - starts with "gid="';
  var query = encodeURIComponent(querySQL);

  var url = 'http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=%KEY%&gid=%GID%&tq=%QUERY%'
  .replace('%KEY%',ssKey)
  .replace('%QUERY%',query)
  .replace('%GID%',gId);

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var content = response.getContentText();    
  var jsonContent = getJSON(content);

  var numCols = jsonContent.table.cols.length;
  var numRows = jsonContent.table.rows.length;

  // Decode objectContent into a two-dimensional array.
  var mydata = [];
  // Then data rows
  for (var row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
    mydata[row] = [];
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++ ) {
      mydata[row].push(jsonContent.table.rows[row].c[col].v);
    }
  }

  return mydata;

}  catch(error) {
  Logger.log('querySpreadsheet: ERROR - ', error);
};    
};

//the content text format is not uniform; try 2 methods to return a JSON object 
function getJSON(contentText) {

try {  

  var regex = /.*google.visualization.Query.setResponse\((.*)\)/g    
  var ret = eval('('+ regex.exec(contentText)[1] +')');
  return ret;

}  catch(error) {

  var ret = regex.exec(contentText)[1];
  var ret = Utilities.jsonParse(ret);
  return ret;

}; 
};
```