# Querying multiple Google spreadsheet tabs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-sheets

EDIT: I've made quite a bit of progress on this but still having trouble. In the code below, I am trying to query two sheets and concatenate the data tables into one data table before turning that data table into a google timeline visualization. However, I've been unable to successfully concatenate the two tables. My code is below (I know the functions are named weirdly and there's some unnecessary code now; just trying to get it to work first and have been adapting code from the single query case).

Thanks for any help!

```
<div id="Timeline"></div>

function drawChart() {
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(  'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q2RkFboIhodAf86xz96UJ5DJEnxJeNYcY9wDbN2INxY/gviz/tq?gid=0&');

  var query2 = new google.visualization.Query(   'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q2RkFboIhodAf86xz96UJ5DJEnxJeNYcY9wDbN2INxY/gviz/tq?gid=1309804722&');

  var data1 = query.getDataTable();
  var data2 = query2.getDataTable();

  var all = google.visualization.data.join(data1,data2,'full',[[0,0]],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,]);  

  all.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }
  var container = document.getElementById('Timeline')
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);

  chart.draw(response, { legend: { position: 'none' } , });
}

google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['timeline'], callback: drawChart});
```

Comment: Please change the permission on the spreadsheet to public, or make another copy without sensitive data public. People helping you shouldn't need to request permission or send you their email address.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that! It's now public.

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to set the 'gid=' parameter of your query url to point to the relevant sheet, you can get this by looking at the url in your browser as you view the sheets in question - see my answer here:
   [How to Perform a Lookup/Filter Across Google Spreadsheets Using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171591/how-to-perform-a-lookup-filter-across-google-spreadsheets-using-google-apps-scri)
2. once you have the result sets in arrays, you can use the Javascript 'concat' method to combine them into one

Comment: Got it, step 1 works, thanks! As for step 2: Any hints on how to do this? I now have two variables: query1 and query2, each of which returns a Google visualization object. How can I turn these two objects into arrays so I can concatanate them, and then turn that concatanated array back into an object so I can pass it through to the chart constructor? Or if I am completely misunderstanding how this works, I still need to figure out how to actually merge the two into one.

Comment: Following up on that comment, I found that Google visualization objects have a join method. I've tried to implement that method into my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/2cLA5/1/ but it is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry, I'm not up to speed with the visualization API as I don't use the HTMLApp - but if you look at the method I posted in the link which extracts the contentText data into arrays, then using the js 'concat' method is pretty straight-forward from there